# Primes and Inverses of an integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I have the following question which I do not understand. Here it is:

> Consider the primes $5$, $7$ and $11$ as n. For each integer from $1$ through $n - 1$, calculate its inverse.

I do not understand what this question is exactly saying. Would I only have to do $1$ through $(11-1)$ and find the inverse of those?

Or is it asking me to find the inverse for the function $n-1$?

If someone could clear this up for me that'd be great!

Comment: Take $n=5$. It is asking you to find the inverses of $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$, modulo $5$. Then, entirely separate problem, tale $n=7$, it is asking you to find the inverses of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ modulo $7$. Next, new problem, $\dots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are working in modular arithmetic.  So for $5$ you are supposed to find $x=\frac 11 \pmod 5, y=\frac 12 \pmod 5$, etc.  $x$ is pretty easy.  For $y$, you need to find $z$ such that $2z=1 \pmod 5$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you it all makes sense but where does the z come from?

Comment: You note that $2 \cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, so $3$ is the inverse of $2 \pmod 5$.  As $5,7,11$ are primes, every nonzero number has an inverse.  These are finite fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are needing to work with modulo arithmetic. The term inverse though can mean a few things. Explanation below.

Additive inverse: $a+(-a)=0$ here we have that $-a$ is the additive inverse of $a$. I don't think you are interested in additive inverses here. Additive inverses mod n are from the group $\mathbb{Z}_n=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$.

Multiplicative inverses: $a(b)=1$. Here we have that $a^{-1}=b$, or that the inverse of $a$ is $b$. You are probably interested in multiplicative inverses, since in mod n they only make sense on the group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*=\{1,2,3,...,n-1\}$. This is because $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse. That is there is not an $x$ such that $0(x)=1$.

With small groups, like $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, you can find the inverses by hand by brute force. However if you know of Euler's algorithm, this can make your life much easier.